# Return an unexported type from a function

Tags: go

Is it considered bad style to return an unexported type from an exported function?
When I've used it, I mostly find it just creates problems.

A better question might be: when is it a good idea to return an unexported type from an exported function.

Answer (score 35):

I would say there's nothing wrong with returning an unexported variable from an exported function. That's what an accessor is by definition.

That said, I would only do that in the case where there was some logic that needed to occur every time the unexported variable needed to be accessed.

EDIT:
I hope I understand your clarified question.

If you have an unexported `type user struct{}` and you return it with `NewUser()`, would that fit your use case? If so, then that is a factory design pattern and is useful in Go if you do not want a 3rd party developer to directly create a `user` type object. That way, your "constructor" or "factory" is the only place to get new instances.

So, is it "bad style"? I'd say it depends on what challenge needs to be overcome.

Comment: I've clarified the question. I meant to ask about unexported types not variables.

Comment: I would like a follow up on this. I have found that I am having to return an `interface{}` since the external calling code has no visibility on that method, but that is leading to some murky code. I need a default value, but I also want to know about that API of the struct that I am returning. Is there no way to have my cake and eat it too? Best I could come up with is having my Receiver function for constructing an exported struct. Not the best since any developer implementing the package can still build the struct by hand if they want, this can lead to poor implementations.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that godoc ignores private stucts so, for example, if this is an open source project and relies on godoc.org for documentation the struct in question wouldn't show up there.

Comment: If we return as an `interface{}` there is no way the methods on that struct are accessible. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I'm using this approach as a builder pattern creating structs that are passed as arguments to my package's functions.

Comment: I like to add, you can even see an example of **returning an unexported type** in `errors` package in GoLang standard library when `errors.New` returns `errors.errorString` structure.

Answer (score 17):

Golang's linters return a warning when you return an unexported type, so I'd say though it's technically possible it's also to be discouraged. [1](https://github.com/golang/lint/issues/210)

One reason is that some code that receives the unexported type cannot utilise it for various "signatures" (eg: types, funcs),  without typing it as an interface (eg: interface{} or otherwise)

eg:

```
package people
type me string
func NewMe() me {
    return "me"
}

// in main.go
package main

type eff struct {
    m *people.me  // <-- cant do this
}

func main() {
   var m people.me // <-- cant do this
   m2 := people.NewMe() // can do this
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I think it's worth posting another viewpoint for others that happen upon this question. A better way to address this is to either define an actual exported interface for that type if the user is meant to interact with it in any way, or just don't return unexported types so you won't have to address this situation. This is primarily a design problem, let me explain.

While it's technically possible to return an unexported type, as shown above, the type must be assigned to `interface{}` for code outside of that package. That to me is a code smell and is something I would seriously question in a code review. Similarly, I would question an exported function/method accepting unexported parameters.

The biggest problem I have with this is that the function signature does not clearly convey its scope of use. Is it an internal function since it returns an internal type? Is it meant to be called by outside consumers since it's an exported function? It's really ambiguous.

Plus, while returning an `interface{}` makes this type transferable, it also breaks type safety to a certain degree. If the purpose of returning `interface{}` is to prevent the user from changing data before passing it to another part of the API, then the secondary API needs to then accept `interface{}` and check for a valid type before using it. Also code smelly and the compiler can't help us with bad calls here.

Comment: Counter point: the errors package returns unexported types via an interface https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/errors/errors.go

Comment: It is not a code smell. You return a type, and the consumer should expect an interface that that type implements. That's the way to decouple implementation from abstraction. It a good practice in OOP to depend on abstraction rather than on implementations.