# how to use function of unexported struct

Tags: go

I have a package where I have unexported struct and exported New function to create it and exported function that runs on this struct (as advised for example here: [Return an unexported type from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470398/return-an-unexported-type-from-a-function)).
If I run the function in the same place the New is called I can run the package function but I am unable to send this entity to another function.
what is the best way to achieve this behavior without the need to have all my code in one function

this for example works:

```
client := package.New()

client.Foo()
```

but this cannot work:

```
client := package.New()

hello(client)


func hello(client interface{}) {

    client.Foo()

}
```

Comment: `client.foo()` cannot work, not in the described scenario, not even in your first "working" example. Did you mean `client.Foo()`?

Comment: yes. you are right. fixed it

Comment: There is no `Foo()` method on `interface{}`. Why did you use `interface{}` here instead of the type returned by `package.New()`?

Comment: @kokoriko ok, you have to let `hello` know what `client` can do, you can do this by declaring an interface, which you can declare either in the client's package or even in the hello's package. Then use that interface as the argument type to `hello`. Something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/HTkxWr3rxop

Comment: You cannot do this. in hello your client is of type interface{} and you simply cannot ever get back the original type (because it is unexported) to call Foo on it. Best advice: Don't get too obsessed by hiding stuff.

Comment: @mkopriva what you showed does not work. hello(client) will not compile since client from the package is not of type fooer.

Comment: @kokoriko no it is not fooer but, it *implements* fooer because in Go interaces are satisfied *implicitly*. (just keep in mind that if `Foo`'s receiver is a pointer then so should be the return value from `New).

Comment: @mkopriva you are right. I tested it and this worked

Answer (score 1):

What your `hello` function essentially needs is something that has a `Foo` function. That's why go has interfaces. There's nothing wrong with returning an unexported type (in fact, it's common and often the right thing to do). What I'd do is this:

```
package foobar

// whatever thing that has a Foo function
type FClient interface {
    Foo()
}

func Hello(client FClient) {
    client.Foo() // will work
}
```

The reason why you'd do it like this is to be able to unit-test this code:

```
package foobar_test

import (
    "testing"
)

type testFC struct {
    callCount uint64
}

// implement interface
func (t testFC) Foo() {
    testFC.callCount++
}

func TestHello(t *testing.T) {
    client := testFC{}
    Hello(client)
    if client.callCount != 1 {
        t.Fail("dependency not called")
    }
}
```

Of course, for more complex dependencies you'd use tools like mockgen or stuff like that, but you get the idea. By definition, a UNIT test focuses on a single UNIT of code. The last thing you'd need to do to test a package unit is to instantiate a type from another package. You should be able to mock everything your code depends on. The best way to do so is interfaces.